# Choosing a suitable optimization technique for warm-starting a nonconvex problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a non convex continuous constrained optimization problem that I would like to solve using a technique that benefits from warm-starting. My understanding is that solvers that utilize interior point method (Like IPOPT and KNITRO) doesn't benefit from warm-starting. Is these another way that can be used?